# Seeking conversion programmes in Israel for women

Tags: gentiles, product-recommendation, conversion-to-judaism, yeshiva-school, state-of-israel

EDIT:

Wow, it has been a while since I created this post on here! Since I created this post, four years have passed and I am now 22 years old and am in my third year of university. I changed university degrees (no longer studying Hebrew, but instead International Relations with Political Science). I have been involved more in the Jewish community in the UK, and I finished a Conservative conversion- from which I took the Hebrew name Eliana Yocheved bat Avraham v' Sarah. I also keep kosher and am shomer Shabbat- at least according to Conservative standards.

Meanwhile, I had no such "luck" with the Orthodox beit din here because I have still not been able to start the process as a student.

I have however had the opportunity to visit a couple of communities in my city; I have been to two Sephardic shuls, and have been recently attending my local Orthodox shul. I have been in contact in particular with the rabbi from that shul, and on a shabbat a few weeks ago we recently spoke about conversion. He informed me that I can keep attending, and then after a while we will speak more about the matter. I have happily accepted that plan, and will keep at it. But even so, as for formally starting the process, it still is not something that is possible for me.

Some rabbis and other converts have advised me for this reason to possibly consider going to Israel in future. This is an option that might be open to me because I will be able to make Aliyah as of next year because of my conversion. However, if conversion there is not possible I would not mind just being able to study in Israel at a seminary for a short time.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The Jewish world of today is complicated, and it is difficult to orient. Making my own way was much eased by direct experiences and dialogues with different people. Basing my view on this premise, I would take a trip to go there and to speak with them (Orah, or any other person you feel connected to or you think you will feel connected to). I would also suggest to search for a Rabbi you will trust to guide you. Also, you may be interested to contact people like the author of [this blog](http://crazyjewishconvert.blogspot.com/) or others like it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I myself have been reading that blog for a few years now, and I indeed find it very helpful. I really do want to visit Machon Ora, and I think I will do so during holidays in my first year of university. In terms of rabbis, I am going to find a United Synagogue rabbi to talk to about conversion, however I've been in contact with a rabbi from the local Chabad; he has been helpful, but he has said he would not be involved in the conversion process when/if I were to begin it...Right now I am reading To Be A Jew by Rabbi Donin to guide me in my observance.

Comment: Maybe try Nishmat? Just FYI, I hate to say this but you may encounter racism in some places (almost certainly not at Nishmat though).

Comment: ^^Thanks for your response, Shalom...I have been informed that Nishmat doesn't offer conversion programmes, but that some people converting at Machon Ora in Jerusalem end up taking classes there. Perhaps of I study at Machon Ora I will end up at Nishmat as well?...As for racism in Israel, it's probably less likely that I will experience racism in Israel than in the UK; here in the predominantly white and Ashkenazi Jewish community, I stick out like a sore thumb and often encounter stares. Israel on the other hand is more diverse.

Comment: I take it from your user name that you are a drummer?

Answer (score 2):

There are least two organizations focused on supporting women converts in Israel through the conversion process

- Machon Meir/Machon Ora ([here](http://www.conversion.machonmeir.net/) and [here](http://www.conversion.machonmeir.net/about-us))
- ITIM ([here](https://www.itim.org.il/en/study-and-preparation-for-conversion/))

In addition here are three serious learning institutes focused on women which might be options to study for conversion or as a source of advice to you for the best institutions to support you further in your conversion process

- [Matan](https://www.matan.org.il/en/about-2/)
- [Neve Yerushalaim](http://nevey.org/)
- [Mayanot](https://www.mayanot.edu/programs_women.asp)